# remove from values from yaml file if they match items in list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, yaml

Here is my yaml file

```
cat host.yaml
list1:
 - host-1
 - host-2
 - host-3
 - host-4
list2:
 - host-5
 - host-6
 - host-7
 - host-8
list3:
 - host-9
 - host-10
 - host-11
 - host-12
list4:
 - host-13
 - host-14
 - host-15
 - host-16
```

Here is my list of hosts

```
cat host.list
host-1
host-5
host-7
host-11
host-16
```

I am trying to write a program/script that takes *host.yaml* and *host.list* as input and if hosts in the *host.list* matches hosts in the *host,yaml* it should edit the yaml and remove those hosts.

In the above scenario *python write_to_yaml.py host.yaml host.list* should write below to yaml file.

```
cat host.yaml
list1:
 - host-2
 - host-3
 - host-4
list2:
 - host-6
 - host-8
list3:
 - host-9
 - host-10
 - host-12
list4:
 - host-13
 - host-14
 - host-15
```

Please forgive me if this is a silly question, I am very very new to Python.

Comment: In the question post you described your **task**, but what is a **problem**? The task is obviously divided into *sub-tasks*, like reading input file `host.yaml` as yaml, reading input file `host.list`, modifying content of `host.yaml`, writing that content back to the file. Which sub-task is difficult to you? Note, that Stack Overflow is not a *code-writer* service: we won't write a code for you. Instead, we could *help* you in writing the code. But for being able to help we need to know which part of code is problematic for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by first installing `pyyaml` via:

```
pip install pyyaml
```

And then you can use the library to read and write your yaml files like so:

```
import yaml

output = {}
host_set = []

# get list of hosts to exclude
with open(r'host.list') as file:
    hosts = yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    host_set = set(hosts.split(" "))

# read host.yaml
with open(r'host.yaml') as file:
    documents = yaml.full_load(file)

    for l, hosts in documents.items():
        output[l] = list(set(hosts) - host_set) # remove items from the read in list of hosts

# write to file
with open(r'output.yaml', 'w') as file:
    documents = yaml.dump(output, file)
```